# Access the JDBC URL of the Thingworx Persistence Provider

Tags: java, jdbc, iot, thingworx

I'm developing an extension using Java for the Thingworx platform, for some reason I want to access the JDBC URL of the ThingworxPersistenceProvider Entity, How can I access it from the Thingworx's Java SDK library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must load the ThingworxPersistenceProvider Thing and use GetConfigurationTable("ConnectionInformation") which has only one row and the column jdbcUrl it's where it's.